# Загрузка документа из iframe и его демонстрация на странице HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!

Вопрос №1 - Почему документ не отображается, а скачивается при открытии странички?
Вопрос №2 - Как сделать чтобы фрейм имел высоту и ширину документа?
Вопрос №3 - Как сделать чтобы при клике на фрейм скачивался документ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну номер один: Не все браузеры поддерживают фреймы (http://caniuse.com/#search=iframe)

Номер два: Есть два варианта - 1) Добавить атрибут width и height с задаными значениями. 2) Добавить это в CSS. Пример:

```html
<iframe src="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/" width="540" height="330" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

```css
#myFrame {border: 0; width: 600px; height: 420px;}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/" id="myFrame"></iframe>
```

Задай ширину, какая тебе нужна но, если у тебя он будет слишком маленьким и не адаптивным, то появится скроллер.

Номер три: можно так, но кликнуть именно на фрейм не выйдет, так ка при клике на фрейм задействуются элементы в фрейме а не в текущем документе. Чуть выше, слева или справа или снизу будет указатель, нажав на который можно будет скачать документ фрейма (не забудьте указать в ссылке `href` такой же как и в фрейме. Но все равно не советую. Лучше создайте ссылку под ним с текстом в стиле

> Скачайте документ нажавши сюда

Пример:

```html
<a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/" style="display: block; z-index: 20;" download><br/><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" src="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/" width="700" height="500"> 
</iframe></a>
```